# How to use load more custom post type data normal or according to on click category tab In WP

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have been developed a website and i has been create a page for portfolio page and I want to use load more data.
I want the data to show up when the page is loaded and in the last show load more button and when I click on a category, it still working of load more.
Check uel: https://w3ondemand.com/demo/

code:

```
<section class="portfolio_section section_padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="menu_portfolio">
                <li><a class="filter-button active_filter_add active_fliter" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shuffle()" data-filter="all">All</a></li> 
                <?php
        
                    $taxonomy = 'our_work_cat';
                    $category = get_terms( array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'our_work_cat',
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                    ) );
                    //print_r($category); die;
                    foreach($category as $categories) {
                        $cat_id = $categories->term_id;
                        $na = $categories->name;
                        $name = explode(" ",$na);
                        //print_r($name); die;
                    ?> 
                    <li><a class="dataclick filter-button active_filter_add" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shuffle()" data-filter="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"><?= $na; ?></a></li> 
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row portfolio_row" id="container">
            <?php

                global $wpdb;
                $i=1;
                $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                    array(
                        'posts_per_page'=>20,
                        //'orderby'   => 'rand',
                        'order' => 'ASC', 
                        'post_type'=>'our_work', 
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
                ); 
                ?>
                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
                $pid = get_the_ID();
                
                $Tid =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM `0n3w_term_relationships` WHERE `object_id` = '".$pid."'",ARRAY_A);
                //$termID = $Tid[0]['term_taxonomy_id'];
                $term_taxonomy_id = array_column($Tid,'term_taxonomy_id');
                $termID = implode(' ',$term_taxonomy_id);

                $cat_name = explode(" ",$termName);
                if($i==2)
                {
                ?>
                <div class="shuffleMe col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 filter <?php echo $termID; ?>" id="overlay">
                    <div class="portfolio_box center_box">
                        <div class="portfolio_box_img">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio_<?= $pid; ?>"><img src="<?php echo  wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) ); ?>" class="" /></a>
                            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/portfolio/view_icon.png" class="view_icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio_<?= $pid; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="portfolio_box_body">
                            <h5><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio_<?= $pid; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <p class="mb-0"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <?php
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            
            <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                </section>
```

anyone helps me...???

Comment: Please try to tidy the format of your code, so that it is easier to read - you can edit your own question.